# При нажатии на форму всплывает ошибка "An invalid form control with name='phone' is not focusable"

Tags: html, jquery, html5

При нажатии на форму  всплывает ошибка:

> An invalid form control with name='phone' is not focusable

после я добавляю к форме "novalidate", ошибка пропадает. Но мне нужно, чтобы при пустом инпуте появлялась ошибка "заполните поле". Подскажите как вызвать эту ошибку (required добавил к инпутам)

```
<iframe name="votar" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<form action="" target="votar" method="post" novalidate>
<input input name="user" placeholder="Ваше имя" required >
<input name="phone" id="phone"  placeholder="+38 (0__) ___-____" required>
<button type="submit" id="pop-btn" formnovalidate="formnovalidate">Получить кредит</button>
</form>
```

Comment: К сожалению не сработало

Comment: да я понял ...извените

Comment: а что там у вас input два раза написан ? `<input input name="user" placeholder="Ваше имя" required >`

Comment: Случайно написал, но от этого ничего не зависит

Comment: вот этот самый input любой должен содержать type=""  понимаете ?

Comment: Исправил все, не заметил. Нашел ошибку, я скрипт один неправильно написал. Всем спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка появляется когда браузер не может сфокусироваться на элементе формы, который required. Например, если этот элемент пустой, но он скрыт от пользователя (через CSS например).

Comment: Елемент не скрыт, поле есть на странице, в него можно вводить данные

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая ошибка. `<input type="text" name="Мессенджер" value="" required>` Она заключалась в том что атрибут value был пустым. Я добавил пробел `<input type="text" name="Мессенджер" value=" " required>` и проблема исчезла. И еще может возникнут из за того что есть стиль display: none если его убрать то должен заработать.
С уважением.